# How can i pass extra parameters to a directive without altering its scope

Tags: angularjs

I have been fightin with angular so much that i am needing some help. What i want to do is simply include a template which differs only on the title, two times in the same html (seems easy but angular is making this so tough..) and i need those templates to use the same scope.
This should be something similar

```
app.directive('datePickerModal', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: 'activityManagementCtrl',
      templateUrl: '/templates/date_modal.html',
      scope: {
       dateTitle: '=title',
       modal_id: '=id'
      }
    }
  });
```

and in my html it is

```
<date-picker-modal title="Start Date" id="start"></date-picker-modal>
<date-picker-modal title="Deadline" id="deadline"></date-picker-modal>
```

I also have a controller which has

```
$scope.activties = [**SOME ACTIVITES**];
```

and its activated in the top of my html file. The thing is that when i access my scope, it has none of the activities, nor anything. So angular is creating a copy of my controller and not using mine. Also, if i remove that "scope: {}", it uses the correct scope, but now i cant pass the information i need to activate the modal and stuff. Any solutions? it seems im in loop, either I loose extra information or the list of activities.
Thanks!

Comment: the directive has an isolate scope. So the scope is ... isolated from the parent controller scope. That's the whole point. If you want to pass activities to the directive, then add another attribute. The controller attribute of the directive is supposed to be the name of the controller that angular instantiates in order to control the directive's template. Not the outer controller.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you're trying to do.  Are you wanting to use the string from the title attribute in the date-picker-modal element?  Because if thats the case, in your directive you would want to do dateTitle: '@title' rather than '=title'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on your angular version if you are on ***1.3*** or above

```
return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: 'activityManagementCtrl',
      templateUrl: '/templates/date_modal.html',
      transclue: true, // <----------------
      scope: {
       dateTitle: '=title',
       modal_id: '=id'
      }
    }
```

you can now access `parentScope` using `scope.$parent`.

Answer (score 0):

https://plnkr.co/edit/ozAstdiMTfuXD8NKXsUI?p=info

So, `$scope.activties = [**SOME ACTIVITES**];` is not on 'activityManagementCtrl'? Because it is working fine. You should not have to use things from the parent controller. Try to make it work with the directive controller, so it can be used with other controllers later and it will be easier to someone else understand. :)

Comment: this is also a good solution, but i rather use the other one, because its on the only place i would be using this modals, and i rather not create another controller. THanks anyways!